# How to set a Firebase value as a CSS property?

Tags: css, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I really need some help with this. I'm using the Ionic Framework on this project.

Right now, all data being displayed is of the interface 'list', which comprises of the following ts file.

```js
export interface list {
    name: string,
    color: string
}
```

I want to create an icon with the color of each list's color value. So far, I've written the following typescript, using a tutorial online. I have no idea if it makes sense or not, but what I do know is that it does not work.

(Order of code --> 1st: TS; 2nd: SCSS; 3rd: HTML)

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AddListPage } from '../add-list/add-list';

//Firebase imports
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

//Observable
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { list } from '../../models/list.interface';
import { PopoverPage } from '../popover/popover';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  list = {} as list;
  listRef: Observable<any[]>;
  listReff: Observable<any>;
  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    public popoverCtrl: PopoverController) {
  }

  ionViewWillLoad(){
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
        this.listRef = this.db.list(data.uid+'/lists').valueChanges();
        this.listReff = this.db.object(data.uid+'/lists/color').valueChanges();
        const color = String(this.listReff);
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--bg', color);
    })
    console.log(this.listRef);

  }
}
```

```css
page-home {
    :root {
        --bg: red;
    }
    
    ion-card{
        ion-icon{
        background: var(--bg);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
      <ion-col *ngFor = "let list of listRef | async">
      <ion-card>
        <ion-icon name="planet"></ion-icon>
      <p>{{list?.name}}</p>
      <p>{{list?.color}}</p>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>            
  </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!